# Update an field in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a class named Customer:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   name   = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   status = models.IntegerField()
```

And the serializer is:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerilizer):
    class Meta:
    model = Customer
    fields = '__all__'
```

Now how can I change/update only the status field using POST method. I am using function base view here.
I want to receive value such as:

```
{
     "status": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would have been way easier if you were using class based views. You can easily create an `UpdateStatusView` that updates `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` send a `patch` request.

However, since you're using function based views, I'll still recommend you use a `PATCH` request rather than a `POST` request, this give better self documentation.

```
def update_status_request(request, id):
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=id)
        customer.status = request.data.get('new_status')
        customer.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Status has been updated'}, status=200)
```

You might also wanna do some extra validation and try...except.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want user post method to update the data, since you are update you can user patch

```
class CustomerUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Customer
       fields = ('status',)


from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import response

@api_view(methods=['post', "patch"])
def api_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
   change instance logic according to u
   instance  = Customer.objects.get()
   if request.method == "POST":
     # post is used for create data so i did for that for update use path
     serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
   else:
      serializer = CustomerUpdateSerializer(instance=instance, data=request.data)
   if serializer.is_valid(raise_exceptions=True):
      serializer.save()
  return response.Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewset for this purpose.

**View**:

```
from rest_framework import viewset

class CustomerViewSet(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

**Url**:

```
path('customer/update/<int:pk>', CustomerViewSet.as_view({'post': 'update'})),
```